# Replacing magnetic field with electric by replacing currents with charges

Tags: electrostatics, magnetostatics

In a region where there are no currents, the magnetic field follows the same equations as the electric field in a region with no charge density.

$$\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0 = \nabla \cdot \vec E$$
$$\nabla \times \vec B = \vec 0 = \nabla \times \vec E$$

If we have a certain distribution of currents that generate a static magnetic field $\vec B_1$, under what conditions can we find a distribution of charges that create a static electric field $\vec E_2$ so that both fields are equal (as vectors, disregarding units) almost everywhere (i.e where there are no sources in either distribution)?

Comment: You should look into "electromagnetic duality" and if you want to compare E and B fields directly, should work in Gaussian units where E and B have the same units.

Answer (score -1):

An ideal capacitor aligned in an infinite solenoid?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good example. The way I know them, they would have to be an infinitely long cylindrical region with non-zero magnetic field, and an infinite "slab" with non-zero electric field, respectively. I was asking if they could be the same field almost everywhere, and if there was a systematic way of turning one into the other.

Comment: well, the solutions are linear, so keep adding infinite solenoids and capacitors until you're satisfied.